# How do Congress members digest 2,000+ page documents?

Tags: united-states, congress, senate, house-of-representatives

Today the Senate approved [a 2,400-page industrial policy bill aimed at countering China](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/06/07/us/politics/senate-china-semiconductors.html?referringSource=articleShare).

My question: how do Congress members digest a 2,400-page bill?

I would’ve fallen asleep by the 5th page.

Comment: TL;DR - they don't, except at a bird's-eye-view level. If a stakeholder has an issue with the proposed legislation, they contact the office of the Representative or Senator. If they want a hand in drafting it, they work with the offices of the Representatives or Senators in the committee or sub-committee originating the legislation. Depending on who the stakeholders expressing a preference are, or how numerous they are, there may or may not be a result. The final vote is mostly a party-line affair.